# How to redirect the user to another page with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm starting with CodeIgniter and I'm having a little trouble linking the pages.

I'm doing it this way:

```
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
<a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('nomeApp/login');?>">Login</a></li>
```

My controller is like this:

```
class Homepage extends CI_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
public function index()
{
$this->load->view('homepage/index');
}
public function login()
{
$this->load->view('login/login');
}
}
```

Comment: so you are not redirecting, you want to include a different view, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redirect between pages use redirect function like

```
redirect('controllername/method');
```

To navigate from navigation menu provide complete link in href

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controllername/method');?>"> Home </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename route go to config/routes.php

```
$route['nomeApp/login'] = 'homepage/login';
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

You may need to include the index.php `<?php echo base_url('index.php/nomeApp/login');?>`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send the user to a different page after a successful login?

If thats the case, you can use `redirect('path/to/yourpage');`

Answer (score 0):

For redirect between pages use redirect function like

redirect('yourcontrollername/methodname');

If you want to rename route go to config/routes.php

$route['App/login'] = 'home/login';